# Can't access filesystem in Go Lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I used Lambda functions before, and if I remember correctly I'm supposed to have ~500Mb of (ephemeral) space in `/tmp`.

Nevertheless, my Go lambda function doesn't seem to interact with the fs properly:

`exec.Command("ls -la /").Output()` returns empty

`exec.Command("rm -rf /tmp/xxx").Run()` returns `fork/exec : no such file or directory`

`exec.Command("mkdir -p /tmp/xxx").Run()` returns `fork/exec : no such file or directory`

It's really weird.
It's using the go1.x environment (thus, I guess amazonlinux:2)

**UPDATE**

I CAN access the fs using Go os functions:

```
os.RemoveAll("/tmp/xxx")

if _, err := os.Stat("/tmp/xxx"); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    if err := os.Mkdir("/tmp/xxx", os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

BUT I really need exec to run afterwards (a binary command), and write a file in that tmp folder. The error in that case is the same (no such file or directory). Even though I've just created the folder with the above commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. The way you use `exec.Command()` is not yet 100% correct. Try the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    o, err := exec.Command("ls", "-la", "/tmp").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", o)
}
```

The first argument to `Command()` is the program you want to run and all the following arguments are the programs arguments.

See https://play.golang.org/p/WaVOU0IESmZ

Comment: indeed! my bad. https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command ty